# how to set iframe's src in firefox extension dialog

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I wanted to set the src of the iframe in dialog dynamically. But the following code does not work.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/"?>
    <dialog id="clockDialog" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
      onload="init();">
      <script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://test/content/clock.js"/>
      <iframe id="content-body" flex = "1" onload="ini()"/>
    </dialog>

    function init() {
      document.getElementById("content-body").src = "http://www.google.com";
    }
```

Is this the correct way to do so? Thank you.

There is a similar question
  [How to dynamically set "src" for browser or iframe element (Firefox extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517294/how-to-dynamically-set-src-for-browser-or-iframe-element-firefox-extension)
which is not answered either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
document.getElementById("content-body").setAttribute("src","http://www.google.com");
```

And you have a typo in your onload call. It should be init();

edit:

And don't forget to set the type attribute. [iframe - XUL | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Attribute/browser.type)

edit 2: The typo remark above is not true. you have the correct call on the dialog onload.

Just tested it with the code I have above and it works.

Comment: Thanks! It works magically! So, = is not same to setAttribute when setting doms?